# use jquery ui resizable work with img from ajax upload,img width and height will change to zero, how to get value before change?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Using jQuery ui resizable work with img from ajax upload, if not set img width and height both(`auto` is not work too) in css,
img will change to `0 0`, can't see the img.
How can I fix it?  catch the img size before `resizable` or any other suggestion?

Thanks.

js

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        data:fd, // new FormData()..
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(html){
            var img = $(html).filter('.img_wp').html();
            $('.container').append(img);

            $('.upload_img img').resizable();
        }
    });
});
```

php

```
$filename = $_FILES['file_upload_tmp']['name'];
$filetmp_name = $_FILES['file_upload_tmp']['tmp_name'];
$filetype = $_FILES['file_upload_tmp']['tmp_name'];
$filetype_accept = $filetype == 'image/jpg';

if($_FILES){
    if($filetype_accept){
        move_uploaded_file($filetmp_name, 'upload/tmp/'.$filename);
        print"
            <div class=\"img_wp\">
                <div class=\"upload_img\" id=\"$layer\">
                    <img src=\"upload/tmp/$filename\">
                </div>
            </div>
        ";
    }
    else{
        print"upload file error, plz upload file type: $filetype";
    }
}
else{
    print"
        <div class=\"upload\">
            <form enctype=\"multipart/form_data\">
                <input type=\"file\" name=\"file_upload_tmp\">
                <input type=\"submit\" value=\"upload\" class=\"btn\">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class=\"container\"></div>
    ";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image may not be loaded when you set `.resizable()`. Try setting it when the image loads.

```
            $('.upload_img img').on('load', function(){
                $(this).resizable();
            });
```